# Getting wrong value in placeholder for user_name

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have created a user profile page in Symfony. When I click on profile, I need to see **user_name**, **email** and **user_image url**. Everything works except the **user_name**. Instead of showing the *name* is shows the *email* again... Like you see in the picture. When I try to change something and save changed everything is changed and saved as supposed but again only email visible.
[Profile screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrcz3.png)

This is the code I have in my **Controller** for the **profile route**:

```
//==
//=== My Profile ====
//==

#[Route('/profile/{id}', name: 'profile')]
public function profile($id, Request $request): Response
{
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->find($id);
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add("user_name", TextType::class, array('attr' => array("class" => "form-control fw-light border-1 border-muted rounded-pill bg-light shadow-sm mt-3 text-muted", "style" => "margin-bottom:15px")))
        ->add("email", TextType::class, array('attr' => array("class" => "form-control fw-light border-1 border-muted rounded-pill bg-light shadow-sm mt-3 text-muted", "style" => "margin-bottom:15px")))
        ->add("user_image", TextType::class, array('attr' => array("class" => "form-control fw-light border-1 border-muted rounded-pill bg-light shadow-sm mt-3 text-muted", "style" => "margin-bottom:15px")))
        ->add("save", SubmitType::class, array('attr' => array("class" => "btn-outline-primary fw-light btn-sm border-1 shadow-sm rounded-pill m-3", "style" => "margin-bottom:15px"), "label" => "Save changes"))->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $user_name = $form["user_name"]->getData();
        $email = $form["email"]->getData();
        $user_image = $form["user_image"]->getData();
       
        $user->setUserName($user_name);
        $user->setEmail($email);
        $user->setUserImage($user_image);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('notice', 'Profile Edited');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('meal');
    }
    return $this->render('meal/profile.html.twig', 
                        ["form" => $form->createView()]
    );
}


//=== Showing all the users===

#[Route('/manageusers', name: 'manageusers')]
public function manageusers(): Response
{
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('App:User')->findAll();
    return $this->render('meal/manageusers.html.twig', array('user' => $user));
}
```

And this is the code I have in the actual **Profile twig** file:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}My Profile
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    <h1 class="page-header fw-light text-center py-5">
        Edit Profile
    </h1>
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-6 ">
                <div class="form mb-4">
                    {{ form_start(form) }}
                    {{ form_widget(form) }}
                    {{ form_end(form) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: During registration, does the data change in the database ?

Comment: Hey @Atchiiii yeah everything gets registered and I can see it normally in the db. Also when I edit something from the profile page stuff change again.

Comment: You arnt doing something odd in the entity manager code are you

Comment: May be the error found here :
`$user_name = $form ["user_name"]->setData();`
Have you changed it to **getData()** like you do for `email` and `user_image` ?

Comment: Hey @RiggsFolly, like what do you mean? the names are also the same there... like user_name is user_name and the functions are the same like setUserName, setEmail... etc

Comment: @Atchiiii I changed that already yeah, cause I was just trying smith. But I changed it back to getData like it should be

Comment: It was just a thought

Comment: All of that get data and setWhatever stuff is unnecessary.  Your data object will be updated when the form is submitted.  Through a dd($user) in there just to convince yourself if needed.

Comment: Hey @Cerad thank for the comment. Is this gonna fix the issue you mean? If I don't have the get and set stuff?

Comment: @Eas My comment was perhaps a bit off-topic and probably would not have solved the issue.  Looks like you have a solution.  My point, which is still valid, is that you have a bunch more code than is needed.  You really want to look at the examples in the docs and maybe even the generated html code to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your User entity you might have a block like this :

```
/**
 * A visual identifier that represents this user.
 *
 * @see UserInterface
 */
public function getUsername(): string
{
    return (string) $this->email;
}
```

You could try to create a function like this

```
public function getRealUserName(): string
{
    return $this->userName;
}
```

And then adapt your form, or either modify (but care about authentification) your getUsername() function